# Angular 2 : How to dynamcially lazy load node_modules from library package based on requested URL

Tags: angular

lets say i have different versions of my library like -

```
player
   |-player1
       |-config.json
       |-player1.module.ts
       |-player1.component.ts
   |-player2
       |-config.json
       |-player2.module.ts
       |-player2.component.ts
```

How can i load player1 version of library if requested URL is xyz.com/p1 and player2 for xyz.com/p2.

i have multiple versions of my library installed in node_modules. based on requested URL i need to lazily load required library version. i can do routing for each version but that will be huge chunk when my versions build to say more than 20, i will have to route for each version. i am looking for a better solution.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: i have multiple versions of my library installed in node_modules. based on requested URL i need to lazily load required library version. i can do routing for each version but that will be huge chunk when my versions build to say more than 20, i will have to route for each version. i am looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

Basically you must define your routes like this

```
{path : 'p1', loadChildren: 'pathToModule#ModuleName'}
```

Comment: I want to lazy load modules outside my app module - which are in node_modules folder.

Comment: I know, check the tutorial and look for information about how to build your custom module loader to replace angular default so you have more flexibility. This requires a full tutorial too much for an answer.